# Android JSon Array is not working with Maplocations class

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I am developing a map application in android i have made maplocation class to pass latitude and longitude and using Json Array to fetch data from MYSQl to display in map.But When I run application it crashed unfortunantely here is my log cat

```
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.icons.draw.view/com.icons.draw.view.DrawIcons}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.icons.draw.view.LocationViewers
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.icons.draw.view.LocationViewers
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at com.icons.draw.view.DrawIcons.onCreate(DrawIcons.java:16)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  ... 11 more
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  ... 21 more
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:112)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:90)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:87)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at com.icons.draw.view.LocationViewers.getMapLocations(LocationViewers.java:102)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at com.icons.draw.view.LocationViewers.init(LocationViewers.java:65)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  at com.icons.draw.view.LocationViewers.<init>(LocationViewers.java:45)
07-07 14:02:26.423: E/AndroidRuntime(366):  ... 24 more
```

And Here is My JSOn Array and loop code to make markers

```
double LAT;
    double LANG;
    String INFO;    
    public List<MapLocation> getMapLocations() {
        if (mapLocations == null) 
        {

        try{
                  jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                  JSONObject json_data=null;
                  for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                         json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                         LAT=json_data.getDouble("lat");
                         LANG=json_data.getDouble("lang");
                         INFO=json_data.getString("info");
                        mapLocations = new ArrayList<MapLocation>();
                        mapLocations.add(new MapLocation(INFO,LAT,LANG));
                     }
                  }
                  catch(JSONException e1){
                      Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No Vehicles Found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  } catch (ParseException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                }





        }
        return mapLocations;
    }
```

Please Help to Remove this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class LocationViewers is not being Inflated.
Just make sure that you are using same name at all for com.icons.draw.view.LocationViewers class.

Then another error is about NullPointerException of any object.